# GRUB is giving an error while loading Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I'm getting an error while loading Windows 10 from GRUB menu. Ubuntu loads perfectly fine. And I can load Windows from boot menu tho, but that isn't always a feasible option. I want my grub menu to work for both OS. I did a fresh installation of both OS on my lenovo G50-45 laptop.

**Points to consider:**
• Installed Windows 10 on 120 SSD.
• Installed Ubuntu 19.04 on 500GB HDD.
• Both drives are GPT partitioned and boots in UEFI.
• I disabled secureboot in BIOS, and fastboot, hibernation in Windows 10.
• I tried updating grub using "sudo update-grub", where it detects the windows boot manager in the drive (/dev/sdb2) and I think it updates too, but it isn't helping.

**Here is how my disks are partitioned:**

> *SDA (500GB HDD)*
>   sda1 | 350MB | /boot/efi
>   sda2 | 30GB | /
>   sda3 | 8GB  | [SWAP]
>   sda4 | 50GB | /home
>
> *SDB (120GB SSD)*
>   sdb1 | 529MB  | Microsoft Windows Recovery Environment
>   sdb2 | 100MB  | EFI system
>   sdb3 | 16MB   | Microsoft Reserved
>   sdb4 | 111GB  | System files.

**This is how my grub menu looks like**

> Ubuntu
>   Advanced Options for Ubuntu
>   Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sdb2)
>   System Setup

**After selecting "Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sdb2)", instead of loading Windows 10, this is the error I get**

> error: no such device : 3C3C B62B.
>   error: disk 'hd1,gp2' not found.
>   Press any key to continue...

After pressing any key, it brings me back to the grub menu

**While on grub menu,and after pressing 'e' for editing windows boot entry, this is what I get**

```
setparams 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sdb2)'  
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod fat
        set root = 'hd1,gpt2'
        if [x$feature_platform_search_hint=xy]; then
            search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set-root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahcil,gpt2 3C3C-B62B
        else
            search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set-root 3C3C-B62B
        fi
        chainloader /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

One thing I have observed is that, after changing boot priority to Windows drive, and again back to Ubuntu drive, the grub menu loads Windows successfully, but only once. The story repeats here after.

After @Nmath's comment, I installed Boot repair and did Recommended Repair, but it also didn't work. Here is link to the Boot Repair log:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8F28WmXZ7x/

Can someone please help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I can't really say what is causing this issue. You Windows disk is intact for sure since you mention you could log in once. Probably there is something wrong with the boot.

I suggest to use **Boot-repair**. It is a tool to repair frequent boot issues while installing multiple OS - particularly Linux and Windows together. Create a live CD or USB from the downloaded ISO and boot into it.

More information can be found here : [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-repair)

Comment: Boot-Repair will not fix Windows issues and will just run the sudo update-grub. But the report may tell us more about all the details of your install. Post link to summary report above in first question. Best to use Ubuntu live installer & add ppa to add Boot-Repair. The Boot-Repair ISO was very old, so not most current version.

Comment: @oldfred boot-repair could find Windows if it is "lost" to GRUB.  If the Windows installation itself is broken, very little can be done from within Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Nmath and @oldfred I installed boot-repair using `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair` `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair` and did a Recommended repair, but it didn't work. Instead now it has created 5-6 more boot entries in my grub menu. Here is the link to my detailed generated report by boot repair. See if it helps. [Boot repair log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8F28WmXZ7x/)

Comment: @Pratik149 I would just verify that you performed boot-repair from a live USB or live CD.  From the paste/dump you posted, it appears that boot-repair "Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sdb2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi".  Does Windows now appear in GRUB?  If the crash happens after you select Windows in the GRUB menu, your issue could be related to the Windows installation.  Also, make sure your BIOS is set to boot to the drive/partition where GRUB is installed.

Comment: @Nmath- I performed boot-repair from my working installed Ubuntu. Windows appeared before also and it appear now also, but yes, it crashes when I select Windows in grub. From the error it gives, it doesn't seem like there is any issue with Windows installation, because when I set windows to boot in bios, it loads perfectly fine. The issue is somewhere in GRUB only. I think I need to edit something in boot menu entry of windows boot manager, but i don't what changes to do. And yes, I set my BIOS to boot from ubuntu/grub drive, but I set it to Windows drive whenever I mostly want to use windows.

Comment: @Nmath, okay, I didn't know that, I thought it would work, as it wasn't explicitly mentioned that it will create any issues with installed ubuntu. Now that you have told, sure I will try boot repair using live ubuntu, and will let you know if it works.

Comment: Sorry, I'm too late to reply, but just to leave an update. I tried running boot-repair from Live USB, but it didn't work. I then deliberately did a clean install of both Windows and Ubuntu, but the problem still persisted. I think the issue is probably with how my ssd and hdd are identified in grub. As of now, the work around for me to start Windows OS is that, every time I start my laptop and when the grub menu loads I have to enter my bios by selecting "System Setup", and simply exit for no reason, and then when the grub menu loads again, the option to load windows works, and I select it.